# Is $1/(1/0)$ undefined, or does it equal zero?

Tags: fractions

Is $1/(1/0)$ undefined, or does it equal zero? By one way of thinking, you could say $1/(1/0)=1*0/1=0$ (taking the reciprocal) and thus equals $0$. But by another, the original expression simply cannot be evaluated because there is division by zero. I think it's undefined (with the reciprocal in fraction division merely being a shortcut to calculate the number of times one fraction can go into the other), but many other sources seem to disagree (with others agreeing). Which is correct?

Comment: whenever part of an expression is undefined, the entire thing is undefined. If you want to write $0$, then just write $0$.

Comment: $1/0$ is meaningless in the real field. Also in the rational field. Or you can say it is not permitted.

Comment: By convention, arithmetic operations within parentheses are to be completed before operations outside of them. By that convention,  the expression is undefined.

Comment: $1/0$ has not reciprocal, because this is not defined in rational numbers.

Comment: To add a complication, if you define $f(x)=1/(1/x)$ in Desmos, and evaluate $f(0)$, Desmos will report that $f(0)=0$, _not_ undefined.